# invalid 'instanceof' operand ol.layer.Base in GeoExt3

Tags: javascript, extjs, geoext3

I am having the following error while integrating tree legend Demo in my Project.

The following Javascript error is coming.

> TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand ol.layer.Base

Please provide help. My code is copy paste from Tree Legend Demo of GeoExt3 from Git Hub.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with js files being pulled.

[Heres a working example at CodePen](http://codepen.io/jesseRules/pen/JYdpmv)

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                'GeoExt': '../../src'
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had to put the code to make this postable. I guess stack hates codePen.

Comment: This js files are fetched properly as per folder in my project

Comment: Maybe open a ticket on the guthub repo then. I just went to their site and rebuilt it and it works fine.  But if you clone it and it doesn't work, report it.